# Hide HTTP request URLs in Flutter

Tags: php, flutter, http, dart, backend

I have an HTTP request, I need to encrypt my HTTP call URL, so it can't be tracked, because when I tried to find the call URL, it was too easy by installing HTTPCanary from google play, so now I am confused. Is there any way to do it in Flutter? (btw I have access to the backend of the URL, and it is written in PHP)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to hide the URL of your HTTP requests from your phone.

---

The reason is very straight forward: your phone needs to know **where to send the request**.

How do you expect your phone to know where to send the request if you encrypt the URL?
You could use the IP address directly, however, that is the same thing - just without the DNS proxy.

See also: [*Encrypt links in Android app*](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/126657/192118)

### Making requests secure

The endpoint (the URL you are trying to access) is what you need to secure *instead*.
Always design your backend security knowing that anyone could send requests at any point in time.

Comment: The problem is that I don't need to hide my end point, I need to hide my hole DNS.

Comment: Also, I think that this is possible since I installed an application found [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.usdmarketapp&hl=en&gl=US), and they completely hide their IP address from requests. And when I try to catch the API requests, it just displays the google Admob ones.

Comment: @Evara have you found any solution for hiding requests from proxy?